# how do I return an object to the array, when the object is only accessible inside .then() of the fetch api

Tags: arrays, asynchronous, fetch-api

i'm trying to fill an array from an existing array using Array.map()
and inside this .map() i'm using the fetch api. now the object that i want to return to the new array,
is only accessible inside the .then() handler of the fetch api but if i try to return something inside this, the object will only be accessible inside the next .then() handler.

```
let accdata=data.map((each)=>{
                fetch(`http://localhost:3001/messenger/checker/${each._id}`,{
                    credentials:'include'
                }).then((res)=>{
                    return res.json();
                }).then((data)=>{
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data!=null){
                        console.log(each);    
                        return each;
                    }
                }).catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err);
                })

            })
```

so this is what i'm trying to do. all the objects that i want in my accdata array are inside the data array,
but i dont really know how to populate the accdata array.

i've tried storing the objects inside a temp array and later assigning it to the accdata,
but since fetch is async, this doesn't work.

let me know if anything needs clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you're not returning the result of `fetch`.

```js
let accdata=data.map((each)=>{
   return fetch(`http://localhost:3001/messenger/checker/${each._id}`,{
     credentials:'include'
   }).then((res)=>{
     return res.json();
   }).then((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
      if (data!=null){
         console.log(each);    
      return each;
   }).catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
   })
});
```

This fills `accdata` with a list of promises that resolve to `each` if the API returned something, or undefined if there was an error or the result was `null`.

If you didn't intend to do that and just fill the array with the result of each API call, I would change this to:

```js
const accdata = await Promise.all(
  data.map(async each => {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/messenger/checker/${each._id}`,{
      credentials:'include'
    };
    return res.json();
  })
);
```

Comment: thanks man! i've got a question though, you say. that the promise would resolve to undefined when there was an error.  is this because i'm not returning anything in the last catch block? if i return "new string", in the catch block, would the promise resolve to this string??

Comment: @yabadaba yes, that's correct. It's better to *not* catch errors though unless you specifically want to ignore them.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution is to use `async/ await` and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).
Use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return an array of `Promise`s and then use `Promise.all()` to await all those promises. Then after you have awaited all promises the return value of `Promise.all()` will be an array with all the serialized API responses.

Here a sample program fetching some dummy data from an API to illustrate the concept. Notice that all the requests are running concurrently and complete in a random order depending on how long each individual request takes.

```js
(async() => {
  const numbersFrom1to10 = [...new Array(10)].map((_, i) => i + 1);

  const allFetches = numbersFrom1to10.map(async id => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/products/${id}`);
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log(`Request for product ${id} was successful!`)
      return response.json() // alternatively: return await response.json()
    }
    throw new Error(`Request for product ${id} failed!`);
  });
  console.log("Waiting for all requests to complete...");
  const allProducts = await Promise.all(allFetches);
  console.log("All requests have completed.");
  console.log(`
  ----------------------------------------------------
  Here a list of all ${allProducts.length} products:
  ----------------------------------------------------`)
  allProducts.forEach(x => console.log(x.title))

})()
```

```css
/* Stackoverflow: show only console */
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
    top: 0;
}
```

> You can ignore the [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) which is just there to [execute the `async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE#execute_an_async_function) function here.

I am using [dummyjson.com](https://dummyjson.com/docs/products) here to get some sample product data here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `forEach` to make the request and push the data item to the `accdata` array each time your response is truthy. Since the request is async you'd need to use `await` to sync your responses. We don't need to use `map` since we're not returning anything from within the iterator instead we use `forEach`.

```
let accdata;
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/messenger/checker';

data.forEach((each) => {
  const res = await (await fetch(`${baseUrl}/${each._id}` {
     credentials:'include'
  })).json()
  if (res !== null) {
    accdata.push({...each})
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?